# Format response from webhooks in Square API in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, square

I'm using the Square API in nodejs. How do you format the refund response from a webhook?

Here's an example. When I get the response from a webhook, the key names are in underscore notation.

```
{
    "amount_money" : {
        "amount" : 3052,
        "currency" : "USD"
    },
    "id" : "luSGCASUgrETw5zbTbxqoMcCNYFZY_TlymxTGdkvplzO5M9Ux6cJItmPhzDQy3iYBHoJqBoTF",
    "order_id" : "jLi6ahIO2pVmcJp70s3gp1IQGRFZY",
    "updated_at" : "2021-01-10T18:32:04.974Z",
    "payment_id" : "luSGCASUgrETw5zbTbxqoMcCNYFZY",
    "version" : 5,
    "status" : "PENDING",
    "created_at" : "2021-01-10T18:32:04.966Z",
    "location_id" : "LJ8GN0VT498M1"
}
```

However, if I generate a refund using the Square API directly the response from the API will give me the same response but with camelcase notation. Is there a way to format this response from a webhook so that it matches what I would get from the API?

Comment: I believe this is due to the webhook being returned as JSON. Technically the APIs return JSON as well, but the SDK formats it into objects for you so it uses language-specific patterns (in this case, camelCase). However, since webhooks aren't a part of the SDK, there's no formatting done for you.

Comment: Ok, it would be great if the SDK had some separate formatting function so I could have the response from web hooks in the same format as responses from the API.